# Automapper Projection with Linq OrderBy child property error

Tags: linq-to-sql, automapper, entity-framework-core, projection

I am having an issue using an AutoMapper (version 5.1.1) projection combined with a Linq OrderBy Child property expression.  I am using Entity Framework Core (version 1.0.0). I am getting the following error:

> "must be reducible node"

My DTO objects are as follows

```
public class OrganizationViewModel
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Organization Name")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
        public virtual int OrganizationGroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual string OrganizationGroupName { get; set; }
        public virtual int StrategyId { get; set; }
        public virtual string StrategyName { get; set; }
        public virtual OrganizationGroupViewModel OrganizationGroup { get; set; }
    }

public class OrganizationGroupViewModel
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Organization Group Name")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
    }
```

My corresponding entity models are as follows:

```
public class Organization
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TimeZone { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        //FKs
        public int OrganizationGroupId { get; set; }
        public int StrategyId { get; set; }
        //Navigation
        public virtual OrganizationGroup OrganizationGroup { get; set; }
        public virtual Strategy Strategy { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual List<AppointmentReminder> AppointmentReminders { get; set; }
    }

public class OrganizationGroup
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
    }
```

My AutoMapper profiles are as follows:

```
public class OrganizationMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public OrganizationMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Task<Organization>, Task<OrganizationViewModel>>();
            CreateMap<Organization, OrganizationViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.OrganizationGroupName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrganizationGroup.Name));
            CreateMap<OrganizationInput, Organization>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }

public class OrganizationGroupMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public OrganizationGroupMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Task<OrganizationGroup>, Task<OrganizationGroupViewModel>>();
            CreateMap<OrganizationGroup, OrganizationGroupViewModel>();
            CreateMap<OrganizationGroupInput, OrganizationGroup>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }
```

When I run the following statements I am able to run and get results from the first 2 statements:

```
var tmp = await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.OrganizationGroup).OrderBy(x => x.OrganizationGroup.Name).ToListAsync();
var tmp4 = await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.OrganizationGroup).OrderBy("OrganizationGroup.Name").ToListAsync();
```

But when I add the ProjectTo I get the error listed above:

```
var tmp5 = await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.OrganizationGroup).OrderBy(x => x.OrganizationGroup.Name).ProjectTo<OrganizationViewModel>().ToListAsync();
var tmp6 = await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.OrganizationGroup).OrderBy("OrganizationGroup.Name").ProjectTo<OrganizationViewModel>().ToListAsync();
```

As some additional information, I am able to OrderBy with Projections working on properties of the parent class, such as:

```
var tmp7 = await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.OrganizationGroup).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ProjectTo<OrganizationViewModel>().ToListAsync();
var tmp8 = await _context.Organizations.Include(x => x.OrganizationGroup).OrderBy("Name").ProjectTo<OrganizationViewModel>().ToListAsync();
```

Anyone run into this issue before?  Looks like I'm trying to do something that is otherwise not supported, is that by design?  Thanks for any help/insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the problem is caused by the `OrganizationGroup` property of the `OrganizationViewModel` class - AutoMapper generates a null check which EF Core doesn't like in the combination with your `OrderBy` (I guess just one of the many bugs currently in EF Core). It can easily be reproduced by the following simple manual projection query:

```
var tmp5a = _context.Organizations
    .OrderBy(x => x.OrganizationGroup.Name)
    .Select(e => new OrganizationViewModel
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        OrganizationGroup = e.OrganizationGroup != null ? new OrganizationGroupViewModel
        {
             Id = e.OrganizationGroup.Id,
             Name = e.OrganizationGroup.Name,
             Active = e.OrganizationGroup.Active,
        } : null,
    })
    .ToList();
```

To fix the issue, configure AutoMapper to not generate `null` check for that property as follows:

```
CreateMap<Organization, OrganizationViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrganizationGroup, opt => opt.AllowNull())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrganizationGroupName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrganizationGroup.Name));
```

Comment: Works great.  Thanks very much!

Comment: In case this helps someone else, I switched over to the current dev build on myget and this looks to have been addressed.

Comment: Looks like the fix didn't make it into a release until 2.0.0-preview1 - https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6921