# Prevent AutoMapper ProjectTo from adding unwanted column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, automapper, entity-framework-core

It seems to me that using AutoMapper `ProjectTo<>` is adding an unwanted (calculated) column to my query. Here's the query:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) CASE
    WHEN [dto].[Id] IS NULL
    THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT)
END, [dto].[Enabled], [dto].[DurationWarningThresholdSec], [dto].[AverageDurationLabel]
```

where that first *CASE & CAST* unnamed column is not really needed, I think. **This is the gist of my issue**.

This is the EF **Core** (maybe that matters) POCO entity being queried:

```cs
public class CountersConfigData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public int DurationWarningThresholdSec { get; set; }
    public string AverageDurationLabel { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
}

// within DbContext.OnModelCreating()
entityTypeBuilder.HasKey(cfg => cfg.Id);
entityTypeBuilder.HasIndex(cfg => cfg.DeletedAt);
```

Here is the destination shape of mapping:

```cs
public class Result
{
    public bool Existing { get; set; }
    public CountersMainConfig Main { get; set; }
}

public class CountersMainConfig
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public int DurationWarningThresholdSec { get; set; }
    public string AverageDurationLabel { get; set; }
}
```

This is the mapping initial setup:

```cs
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<CountersConfigData, Result>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Main, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Existing, opt => opt.Ignore());

    cfg.CreateMap<CountersConfigData, CountersMainConfig>();
});
```

I understand that I could project to inner type, `CountersMainConfig`, and then manually create the outer type instance. But I have further cases similar to this one, with more complicated outer types, so I'd like to sort this out for all of them.

If I actually project to the inner type, that first column goes away from generated query. What am I missing? TA

**EDIT** I created a simplified solution just to confirm the issue before asking here. Afterwards I also tried changing outer destination class by making `Existing` a float, or by removing it, with no luck.

Comment: Try setting a constant value instead of using `Ignore`: `.ForMember(dest => dest.Existing, opt => opt.UseValue<bool>(false));`. Not very clean, though. The `Ignore` should work. Perhaps if you set the boolean property as nullable the `Ignore` would be applied? Perhaps your mapping is being overridden after the initial definition and the `Ignore`gets lost?

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the same SQL is generated even after dropping `Existing` property completely, so somehow this leads me to thing that such property should not really matter. It seems to be related to the nested structure of destination. I'll try though.

Comment: Just to confirm that boolean property was not the issue. @Ivan Stoev answer did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is similar to [Automapper Projection with Linq OrderBy child property error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950128/automapper-projection-with-linq-orderby-child-property-error/39965284#39965284), so is the solution - configure `AutoMapper` to not generate `null` check for the `Main` property:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Main, opt => { opt.AllowNull(); opt.MapFrom(src => src); })
```