# Automapper's ProjectTo throws serilization error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

I am trying to use Automapper's `ProjectTo()` extension method and I am running into an error:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.

The inner exception is:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'DataContracts.StateContract'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

Call I am making looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<OriginContract> Origins()
{
    return contextProvider.Origins.ProjectTo<OriginContract>(automapperConfiguration);
}
```

And the classes I am using are like this:

Contracts:

```
public class OriginContract
{
    public int OriginId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public StateContract State { get; set; }
}

public class StateContract
{
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The entities have the same properties and names (I copied and pasted from one to the other.)  You can [see them here](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/c8ed812c807b0314c0cd41ac4f78f393) if you like.

One important note, if I take out the `State` property from the Origin class, it works fine.  So this error has something to do with trying to have a Origin class that contains a State class.

Any ideas how to get past this error?

Comment: I think this may have to do with how automapper maps to nested objects: try creating a mapping between `StateContract` and its entity, then update your mapping for `OriginContract` to `CreateMap<Origin, OriginContract>().ForMember(x => x.State, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.State))`.

Comment: And where is the mapping? Anyway, take a look at [Automapper Projection with Linq OrderBy child property error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950128/automapper-projection-with-linq-orderby-child-property-error/39965284#39965284), I'm almost sure this is the same issue, so the same solution should work.