# EF Core 3.0 and OrderBy after Automapper ProjectTo issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm seeing an error using Automappers ProjectTo on EF Core 3, when trying to order on a column inside a class property.

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SettingsDto Settings { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsDto
{
    public int VoucherStartNum { get; set; }
}

var mapperCfg = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();
    cfg.CreateMap<CustomerSettings, SettingsDto>();
});

// This is working.
var workingSelect = _db.Customer
    .Select(x => new CustomerDto
    {
        Name = x.Name, 
        Settings = new SettingsDto
        {
            VoucherStartNum = x.Settings.VoucherStartNum
        }
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Settings.VoucherStartNum)
    .ToList();

// This generates an error.
var errorProjection = _db.Customer
    .ProjectTo<CustomerDto>(mapperCfg)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Settings.VoucherStartNum)
    .ToList();
```

`errorProjection` throw the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'OrderBy<Customer, int>(
    source: DbSet<Customer>, 
    keySelector: (c) => Property<Nullable<int>>(Property<CustomerSettings>(c, "Settings"), "CustomerId") == null ? null : new SettingsDto{ VoucherStartNum = Property<CustomerSettings>(c, "Settings").VoucherStartNum }
    .VoucherStartNum)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

This is the expression generated for `errorProjection`

```
EntityQueryable<Customer>.Select(
    dtoCustomer => new PaymentsController.CustomerDto
    {
        Name = dtoCustomer.Name,
        Settings = (dtoCustomer.Settings == null)
            ? null
            : new PaymentsController.SettingsDto
            {
                VoucherStartNum = dtoCustomer.Settings.VoucherStartNum
            }
    }).OrderBy(x => x.Settings.VoucherStartNum)
```

I'm guessing that this is due to the null check included by AutoMappers ProjectTo function. How can I fix this?

Comment: `ProjectTo` should be the last call.

Comment: Any way around that? In this case, I'm sending the projected result to the client, and the client have the option to make a request again, and order on these columns returned by the projections.

Comment: ForMember->AllowNull will skip that check, but you're walking a thin line here :) You might want to check expression mapping which can help here.

Comment: Thank you. There seems to be [some mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950128/automapper-projection-with-linq-orderby-child-property-error/39965284#39965284) about this being a bug in EF Core/Automapper. Can you elaborate on why you think I'm walking a thin like here? :-) It's simple projections that can be done in SQL as well.

Comment: Because EF handles entities, not projections. Clearly it doesn't work with LINQ. Take the AM expression and run it. You'll get the same error. And that's exactly what your link says.